# VM restart on Southeast Asia Region

Tags: virtual-machines

Today, few of my VM on azure (centos) restart . I hosted it in Southeast Asia (Singapore). This problem impact to some of service.

1.Is there any issue about it ? 
2.Is there any alert if there is problem with azure cloud ? (not VM monitor, but whole services)

Best Regards

Comment: I think the following MS blog answered your question.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/securing-azure-customers-from-cpu-vulnerability/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this was related to the Intel flaw. Our Azure VM underwent 'forced maintenance' on the evening of the 3rd/4th. You should have received an email telling you this was going to happen.

One application we use has a licence key check based on CPU ID, MAC Address and OS Activation Code. The forced maintenance invalidated this key (presumably they moved the VM to a different host). This can also occur if your re-size the VM.

Comment: Some more detail would be appreciated.